# Vulcanize local Polymer app

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, vulcanize

We use **Polymer** to build a **local app**. Each Polymer element has a *.html* and *.css* (compiled from *.scss*) file.

Does the use of [vulcanize](https://github.com/Polymer/vulcanize) (it concatenates the JS and Polymer elements into one file) provide an advantage? Does the use of some **minify** tool after vulcanize provide any advantage?

Once again, it is a **local (only) app** so I mostly care about *performance* and *speed*.

Comment: The use of vulcanize is mostly due to the limits of HTTP 1.1. When your server supports HTTP/2, vulcanization would actually be discouraged.

Comment: This is local (only) app, is this thing with HTTP/2 also applies to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Concatenating Web Components With Vulcanize](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/articles/concatenating-web-components.html).

> The short answer is “don’t guess it, test it”. There is always a
>   trade-off when it comes to concatenation but tools like WebPageTest
>   can be useful for determining what your true bottlenecks are.

Answer (score 1):

You can use chrome browser developer tools (acess via menu) and compare application load speed for plain, vulcanized, minified versions or combinations of them. 
Then decide which bests suits your needs.

Comment: Well this is not what I can do right now, because now we load 'loading' or 'app' using Angular ng-show.

Comment: Are the benefits applies even to local app? :)